# How to display a PNG properly on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, png, transparency

How would I go about displaying a png with transparent parst on JFrame.
I currently have this code and all is good, but it displays the transparent parts grey!

```
private static void createAndShowSplashScreen() throws Exception {
    Image image = ImageIO.read(TCPServer.class
            .getResource("images/splash.png"));
    BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) image;

    frame = new JFrame("Splash");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)) {
        {
            setOpaque(false);
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
    frame.setBounds((int) (java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getScreenSize().getWidth() / 2 - img.getWidth() / 2),
            (int) (java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
                    .getHeight() / 2 - img.getHeight() / 2),
            img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    frame.setOpacity(0f);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

THX for the help!
Sincerely Roberto!

EDIT:
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3TT9.png)

PROBLEM SOLVED:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(TCPServer.class
            .getResource("images/splash.png"));
    BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage) image;

    frame = new JFrame("Splash");
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)) {
        {
            setOpaque(false);
        }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
    frame.setBounds((int) (java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getScreenSize().getWidth() / 2 - img.getWidth() / 2),
            (int) (java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
                    .getHeight() / 2 - img.getHeight() / 2),
            img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    RoundRectangle2D r = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 25, 25);
    frame.setShape(r);
    frame.setOpacity(0f);
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Upload the image to a site where we can see it.  BTW - try setting the `JFrame` background color to `Color.YELLOW`.  Does anything change?

Comment: This `frame.setOpacity(0f);` isn't helping your case out at all.

Comment: It has a for loop in a thead under it which makes it fade in

Comment: The image is displaying link in edit

Comment: @AndrewThompson I guess what's happening is that the OP is seeing the `JFrame` underneath the `JLabel`. Isnt it ?

Comment: What the ..huh?  When I said 'link to the image' I did not mean 'link to a screenshot of the image appearing over your IDE'.  I meant **'link to the image *with transparency*'**

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/19SN3w8.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if this suits your particular case but how about changing the shape of the `JFrame` to match the image ? The [`setShape(Shape shape)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setShape) lets you use any shape from the `geom` package. I see that this is a splash screen and will be undecorated, probably, so setting the shape should do the trick.

Comment: will try give me 10 mins

Comment: Good lateral thinking.  :)